# How can I execute Terminal Commands by an URL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

**Hi!** I've searched about it here, but **I did not understand** what I need to do to get this working or how can I do this.

What I need is to know how can I **execute a Terminal Command or a Bash Script with an argument by typing `foo://bar` on my browser, or by typing `xdg-open foo://bar` on my Terminal**, like the APT-URL (`apt://foo` or `xdg-open apt://`). I need to do this because I'm developing a bash script that will need this function (and because *I want to facilitate my life when I need to use a command but I'm on my browser and I don't want to open terminal* too).

Also, are this case-sensistive, right? (There is difference between `command://argument` and `CoMmAnD://argument`) At least, when I type `apt://foobar` and `ApT://foobar`, nothing changes.

**Please, don't mark this as a duplicate, because the duplicates are very confusing and I don't really know the difference beetwen Protocol Handler and URL Scheme.**

Can you **help me, please?** I will be **very thankfull** if you can help me! **Very thanks!**

[image]   [image][image][image]

Comment: Who and why downvoted my post? The downvote is because of what?

Comment: Probably because you are not showing much research effort ("[...] I don't really know the difference beetwen Protocol Handler and URL Scheme.")

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to execute and display some Linux commands from the web browser:

create a script.cgi under `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<h1>Execute ps command</h1>"
echo "<pre> $(ps aux) </pre>"
echo "</body></html>"
```

make it executable `sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.cgi` then this url http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi in your browser.

Comment: @Panki I research many times, but i really did not found anything about it. Also, knowing what is Protocol Handler or knowing what is an URL Scheme does not makes so much difference: If I get this working, it's already perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This don't worked for me, I get "Connection Refused". I tried to type "localhost/usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.cgi" too, but nothing changed. Also, can I create an "foo://" prefix for some shell script?

Comment: @Felipecconde Check the status of `apache2` service.

Comment: @apache2
$ systemctl status apache2
Unit apache2.service could not be found.

And, hm, "apache2" command doesn't worked for me.
No command found, but it can be installed with:
sudo apt install apache2-bin

Also, apache2 doesn't appeared on the system monitor.

Am I checking it wrong?

Comment: @Felipecconde Install apache2 : `sudo apt install apache2`

Comment: That folder doesnt exist. Btw, I moved it to the /srv/http (locahost root). When i type the url, it doesnt run the file, just show its content.

Also, thx for your help. Lol, it passed so many years.